# There are infinitely many subsequences of a bounded sequence $(a_n)_{n \geq 1}$ which are convergent.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Let $(a_n)_{n \geq 1}$ be a bounded sequence of real numbers. Then

1. There is a subsequence of $(a_n)_{n \geq 1}$ which is convergent.
2. There are infinitely many subsequences of $(a_n)_{n\geq 1}$ which are convergent.

My Attempt:

If we take a term of the sequence and repeat it infinitely then it becomes a constant subsequence of a given sequence. So option 1 is trivially true.
Note that the given sequence is not necessarily bounded.

For 2, take a sequence {1,2,1,2,1,2,1,2...} Which is bounded. We see that there are three subsequences {1,1,1,1...}, {2,2,2,2,...}and{1,2,1,2,1,2,1,2,...} Out of which {1,1,1,1...}, {2,2,2,2,...} are convergent. These are not infinitely many. So option 2 discarded. But I have seen any where that option 2 is a result which is always true. Please clear my doubt giving some hints or proofs.

Comment: Given a sequence $(a_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$, a subsequence is a sequence of the form $(a_{\varphi(n)})_{n\in\mathbb N}$ where $\varphi:\mathbb N\to\mathbb N$ is a *strictly increasing map*. Your proof of $(1.)$ is wrong, and the result is non trivial.

Comment: Your first observation is usually called  [Bolzano Weierstrass Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bolzano%E2%80%93Weierstrass_theorem) and your proof isn't correct since the constatn sequence may or not be a subsequence (take for example $a_n=1/n$).

For the second statement, tak a CONSTANT sequence $a_n=a$. then every subsequence is again the constant sequence, so teher is only 1 subsequence.

Comment: (1) trivially implies (2). If you start from  a convergent subsequence, you produce infinitely many convergent subsequences just by deleting different terms.

Comment: The question post [Help me understand the proof for Bolzano-Weierstrass Theorem!](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2105011/help-me-understand-the-proof-for-bolzano-weierstrass-theorem) contains the proof of BW, and along with PierreCarre's trivial comment, we can mark this as a duplicate.

Answer (score 3):

To prove (1), please look up [Bolzano-Weierstrass theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bolzano%E2%80%93Weierstrass_theorem)

For (2), note that any subsequence of your original bounded sequence is going to be bounded as well. Therefore, we know such subsequence will, itself, contain a converging subsequence (by (1)). Since there are an infinite number of distinct subsequences of the original sequence (if the sequence is not constant after a certain index), there are an infinite number of converging subsequences.

Comment: What about a CONSTANT SEQUENCE? Every subsequence is, in fact, the same!!!

Comment: I think my doubts are not addressed properly.

Comment: My first doubt : When a sequence is given. If we select one term of the sequence randomly and repeat it infinitely many times then it becomes a subsequence which is always convergent whether the original sequence is bounded or not. I know that convergent sequence has a unique limit point. My 2nd doubt : By taking an example in "My Attempt" and show that this sequence has infinitely many convergent subsequences.

Comment: @Merabhai you can only do this , select a element and repeat it infinite times only when range set is finite.

Comment: @MeraBhai I think you misunderstand the definition of a subsequence. A subsequence must be indexed by an infinite subset of $\mathbb N$. You're trying to index it by just one element repeated over and over and over. That's not a subsequence.

Comment: (1) is a link only response, Stefan, which make better comments, and are subject to deletion.   Your answer in total, fails to answer the question, but lo and behold, it's already been asked and answered more proficiently.

Comment: Cool, just downvote it.

Answer (score 2):

As many pointed (1) is the classical Weierstrass---Bolzano theorem.

For (2) your doubts are coming from confusing a sequence with the the values it takes.

Consider the sequence $a_{n}=2$. Then, $a_{2n}$ and $a_{3n}$ are (typically considered) different subsequences of $a_n$, even if they are the same sequence.

They are different subsequences because they have different indeces. Formally a subsequence is $a_{\phi(n)}$ where $\phi : \mathbb N \to \mathbb N$ is a strictly increasing function, and different functions give different subsequences.
The issue is that we are often a bit careless when it comes to this, thinking of a subsequence as the values it takes.

For (2) note that if $a_n$ has a convergent subsequence $a_{\phi(n)}$ then any subsequence of $a_{\phi(n)}$ is a cnvergent subsequence of $a_n$.

Comment: You know full well this question was asked before, likely a number of times.  Please do not rush to answer until *after* even a basic search for a dupe.

Answer (score 0):

Mere bhai , you can only do this , select a element and repeat it infinite times only when range set is finite.

The idea of this proof is that , if a sequence is bounded then it's means it's range set is bounded . And you may also know about that every bounded subset of $\mathbb{R}^k$ lies in compact subset of $\mathbb {R}^k$ and its a fact that sequence in compact matric space must have a sub sequence in it.